# How to add XY point and update attributes with ArcPy 10.0

Tags: python, arcgis-10.0, arcpy, cursor

I would like to create a script tool that takes 3 parameters in ArcMap:

1. Google maps coordinate (e.g. -33.876846, 151.215117)
2. text string
3. text string

The coordinates would define the XY geometry, and the two strings would be the attributes for the new point ("Report" and "Hyperlink")
I am limited to ArcMap 10.0, so I can't use the .da module. I think I have the geometry figured out, but not the attributes.

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("CURRENT")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

#for use in ArcGIS script - gets input coordinates
coordsIn = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)

#get Report name
Report = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)

#get Report Hyperlink
Hyperlink = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

#delimits coordinates by comma and places them in list "coordsplit"
coordsplit = coordsIn.split(",");

#defines coordinates
X = float(coordsplit[0])
Y = float(coordsplit[1])

#assign feature class to edit
featureClass = "D:\\data\\testing\\testing.gdb\\ReportsGDA"


#create insert cursor
rowInserter = arcpy.InsertCursor(featureClass)

#create update cursor
rowUpdater = arcpy.UpdateCursor(featureClass)

#assign coordinates to point object
pointGeometry = arcpy.Point(X,Y)


# Use the insert cursor to put the point object
# in the feature class
newPoint = rowInserter.newRow()
newPoint.Shape = pointGeometry
rowInserter.insertRow(newPoint)

#update attributes
for feature in rowUpdater:
    if feature.Report == None:
        feature.Report = Report
        feature.Hyperlink = Hyperlink
```

Comment: Shape@ is arcpy.da, have a read of http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001v000000. In the non da cursors use getValue and setValue with the name of the field to read/write attributes see http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//000v000000nv000000 for update/insert.

Comment: You should have a look at the following posts, some of it might be helpful to you: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/134243/using-arcpy-to-zoom-to-y-x-string-coordinate-pair-copy-pasted-from-google-maps/134303#134303

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You stated in a comment in PolyGeo's answer that you have the geometry working. Updating the attribute is very similar. You want to update the row object before inserting it.

Remove the last `for` loop and update the code prior to this:

```
# Use the insert cursor to put the point object
# and attributes in the feature class
newPoint = rowInserter.newRow()
newPoint.Shape = pointGeometry
newPoint.Report = Report
newPoint.Hyperlink = Hyperlink
rowInserter.insertRow(newPoint)
```

Comment: Works perfectly, much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

Your code does not look like it could write a geometry at 10.0 because, as @MichaelMiles-Stimson says, SHAPE@ tokens are an arcpy.da (10.1+) construct.

The approach to this that I would use at 10.0 is:

1. Write the geometries into a feature class by using code like that on the [Writing Geometries](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//002z0000001v000000) help page that @MichaelMiles-Stimson gave a link to.
2. Use an insert cursor to write a table with a common field and the attributes
3. Use Join Fields to join the attributes onto the features

Comment: thanks for the input. I have the geometry working, but still not sure how to work the attributes. I can get it working with a for loop (as in http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/60458/how-to-edit-attribute-tables-using-python-arcpy), but this just overwrites all of the attributes in the feature class with the same values.